# Setting chromeoptions language and setting locales in dockerfile dont work in container

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile, selenium-chromedriver

I want to set the browser language in the docker container to german.

I set the language in the chrome options like this. And this works when i execute the tests outside of docker using the VS test explorer:

```
ChromeOptions options = new();
options.AddArguments("--incognito");
options.AddArguments("--ignore-ssl-errors=yes");
options.AddArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
options.AddArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.AddArguments("--disable-infobars");
options.AddArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
options.AddArguments("--lang=de_DE");
```

And i also tried setting the locales in the dockerfile:

```
ENV TZ="Europe/Vienna"
# Install locales package
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales

# Set the locale to German
RUN sed -i -e 's/# de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
    dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive locales && \
    update-locale LANG=de_DE.UTF-8

# Set environment variables
ENV LANG de_DE.UTF-8  
ENV LANGUAGE de_DE:de  
ENV LC_ALL de_DE.UTF-8  

# Optionally, you might need to regenerate the locales
RUN locale-gen de_DE.UTF-8
```

But the browser starts still in english. I cant find any other solution and hope that i can get help here.
I also dont understand why the chrome options are not setting the chrome browser to german in the container when i add the argument for it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

If working with a `selenium.hub` container, the language/locales have to be set in the docker-compose file too, as the container will always set the environment variables to en-EN by default.

When the container was running, i checked the details of the container which looked like this:
[image]

After that i added these ENV variables to the docker-compose file and it worked:
[image]